# Cannot read property 'prodid' of undefined at ClientEditComponent.updateClient

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular5, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I have a  Component named as "Client Component" using firebase for database purposes, material component for design purpose.
I am working on CRUD operations i did create, delete but facing an issue in Update. The Client data show in grid and when i clicked edit icon Child component called and "Client-edit form" is opened and every fields in the form are also filled with previous data but after changing and click the update button facing an error.

> Update Code.

```
updateClient(prod){
    //this.clientservice.onUpdate(prodid);
    this.items.doc(prod.prodid).update({
      fname: this.fname,
      lname: this.lname,
      cemail: this.cemail,
      caddress: this.caddress,
      crole: this.crole,
    }).then(() => {
      console.log('Updated');
    })
  }
```

> Service

```
 onUpdate(prod){
        this.pro.collection("client").doc(prod).update(prod.prodid).then(function() {
            console.log("Document successfully Updated!");
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
        });
    }
```

> Get data in clientform form grid.

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      fname: ['Test', Validators.required],
      lname: ['New test'],
      email: [''],
    });
    this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      address: ['Test2', Validators.required],
      role: [''],
    });

    /////Client-Edit////
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.id = params['id'];
        this.editMode = params['id'] != null;
        this.initForm();
      })
  }

  id: string;
  editMode = false;

  initForm() {
    if (this.editMode) {
      let items: any = this.clientservice.getClient(this.id)
        .then((res:Client)=>{
            //this.client = res;
            this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
              fname:[res.fname],
              lname:[res.lname],
              email:[res.cemail],
            })
            this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
              address:[res.caddress],
              role: [res.crole]
            })
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Not enough data to help you here. Share the error which you are getting (scrrenshot if possible to get the line number etc) .

Comment: ClientEditComponent.html:60 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'prodid' of undefined
    at ClientEditComponent.updateClient (client-edit.component.ts:36)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ClientEditComponent.html:60)
    at handleEvent (core.js:13543)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15052)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14639)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:9958)
    at eval (core.js:10583)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eval (platform-browser.js:2628)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4736)

Comment: sorry cannot upload screen shot of error, the abve is line of code is error which i am facin, When i clicked update button face this error. @Shaskshank Vivek

Comment: Whats there on `client-edit.component.ts` line numer: **36** ? From the code and error, I can guess that `prod` object is coming as `undefined` and so `prodId` is not available .

Comment: "Prodid" is unique id of Client table, i am using Cloud firestore for database purpose.